# What is the rails way equivalent of mailto: and tel:?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My model has contact:string and email:string attributes. In pure HTML, we can write

`<a href="mailto:sample@email.com">email us</a>`

and

```
<a href="tel:123-456">123-456</a>
```

How do we convert these two into rails code assuming my model name is `@sample`. My guess would be something like

```
<%= link_to @sample.email, "#" %>

<%= link_to @sample.contact, "#" %>
```

What should be in the `"#"` ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use `mail_to "me@domain.com"` instead of `link_to`.

For `tel:` do `link_to @sample.contact, "tel:#{number}"`

Comment: `<%= link_to @sample.contact, "tel:#{@sample.contact}" %>`

Comment: Also for those needing a button  
`<%= button_to 'Link', "tel:#{@phone_number}", class: 'phone-number-class', method: :get %>`

Comment: Since Rails 6.1, `phone_to` helper is available, as mentioned in later answer.
Maybe correct answer here should be changed.

Answer (score 7):

Use:

```
<%= mail_to "me@domain.com", 'TEST' %>
```

more options [APIdock mail_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/mail_to).

For `tel_to`, there is a GEM, see [gem tel_to_helper](https://github.com/swordray/tel_to_helper)

Answer (score 4):

A simple `tel_to` helper for `tel:` links:

```
def tel_to(phone_number)
  phone_number = number_to_phone(phone_number)
  link_to phone_number, "tel:#{phone_number}"
end

tel_to(8424176704)
# => <a href="tel:842-417-6704">842-417-6704</a>
```

And the existing `mail_to` for `mailto`:

```
mail_to("Dorian", "dorian@doma.io")
# => "<a href=\"mailto:Dorian\">dorian@doma.io</a>"
```

Answer (score 3):

For displaying clickable email links use `mail_to` instead of link_to.

```
= mail_to 'aquis.tech@gmail.com', 'Email Me'
# <a href="mailto:aquis.tech@gmail.com">Email Me</a>
```

Reference: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-mail_to

---

For displaying clickable Phone number link (**Rails 6.1.0 and above**) use `phone_to`

```
= phone_to '+917977519229', 'Call Me'
# <a href="tel:%2B917977519229">+917977519229</a>
```

For older versions you can use manual link_to helper with href as `tel:+917977519229` or can use gem as suggested in other answers.
Reference: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-phone_to

---

Also in case you might need, Rails 6.1.0 has also added `sms_to` helper which is similar to `phone_to`. Clicking on the link will open default SMS app.
Reference: https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-sms_to

Answer (score 1):

Use gem [tel_to_helper](https://github.com/swordray/tel_to_helper).

```rb
tel_to '000-000-0000'
# => <a href="tel:000-000-0000">000-000-0000</a>
```

```rb
tel_to 'My phone number', '000-000-0000'
# => <a href="tel:000-000-0000">My phone number</a>
```

```rb
tel_to '000-000-0000', 'My phone number', target: '_blank'
# => <a href="tel:000-000-0000" target="_blank">My phone number</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mail_to`.

```
<%= mail_to @sample.email, "Email us" %>
```

For telephone numbers, you might have to write your own helper or just concatenate the "tel:" into the url.

Answer (score 0):

`phone_to` is also available for phone numbers

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use it?